# JQuery - loading external text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to load the contents of an external text file in to a div when a tab is selected but it doesn't seem to be loading the contents. What is the problem?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/common.css" />
    <script src="JS/common.js"></script>
    <title></title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="tab1" name="#tab1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab2" name="#tab2">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab3" name="#tab3">Specifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab4" name="#tab4">Gallery</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="tabContent1"></div>
      <div id="tabContent2"></div>
      <div id="tabContent3"></div>
      <div id="tabContent4"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

External JS (common.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab1").click(function() {
    $("#tabContent1").load("test.txt");
  });
});
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Nothing, there is no error outputted.

Comment: Check network tab in developer tools/firebug and see a path to file which is loaded after you click #tab1

Comment: what are the contents to test.txt?

Comment: Check the network tab and see what the HTTP traffic looks like. You might be getting a server error, 404, MIME error, or who knows what.

Comment: what about file path ?

Comment: Contents of `test.txt` is just random text. The network tab isn't showing any errors however the text file isn't shown there.

Comment: I can access the text file if I type the file path into the URL bar.

Comment: `however the text file isn't shown there` Are you checking it after click? Code is correct and it should work fine. After you click #tab1 new entry should appear in network tab.

Comment: It's not showing after clicking the tab either

Comment: try to put  an alert inside click callback and see if it appears after you click that link. Also, check that external file is really loaded.

Comment: I put the following code in the function and the alert didn't show.

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tab1").click(function () {
    alert("js is working");
  });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a code like this:

```
  $("#tab1").click(function() {
    $("#tabContent1").load("test.txt");
  });
```

But there is a line

```
 $("#tabs li:first a").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
```

Which changes its id from `#tab1` to `#current`, so you need to update your code like this:

```
  $("#current").click(function() {
    $("#tabContent1").load("test.txt");
  });
```

Or, what is better, add class current instead of changing an id:

```
$("#tabs li:first a").addClass("current")
```

Comment: That worked, however if I click a different tab before clicking `tab1` the content doesn't load but if I click `tab1` first it loads.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax seems correct
make sure the Url of the file is correct
make sure the test.txt contains something

Comment: If I type the URL in to the address bar I can access the text file and see it's contents.

Comment: what is the url that you are typing in the address bar?? and check the debug console and look at the request you are sending

Comment: yes the request details are on the network tab.. is the page where this script is present also on the site? if yes please provide the url of the page and ill be able to check the request

Comment: The URL for the JS is COM601_Assign1/JS/common.js